# How to calculate capacity using Shannon and path-loss?

Tags: digital-communications, fading-channel, channel, white-noise

I am working on tasks offloading on edge computing. I need to find the transmission delay, through calculating Shannon capacity-theoretical maximum data rate- when sending results from the server back to the user's device. Using the notation:

- ( B_v ): wireless bandwidth of the server
- ( P_v ): server's transmission power
- ( D ): Distance

$$ r_{vi} = B_v \log_2 \left( 1 + \frac{P_v |h|^2}{\omega_0 D \theta_{vi}} \right)$$

\begin{align*}
\text{Parameters for Shannon’s formula:} \\
\bullet & \text{ Path loss exponent } \theta = 2.5 \\
\bullet & \text{ Channel fading coefficient } h = 0.7 \\
\bullet & \text{ White Gaussian noise power } \omega_0 = 3 \times 10^{13}
\end{align*}

**Transmission Delay**

Now, the transmission delay for sending the processed data task $D$ back to the user’s device is denoted as **Transmission Delay** and is calculated by:

$Transmission_{Delay} = \frac{Data size}{r_{vi}}$

Given that the path loss is included in the denominator in the Shannon formula*, is this the correct formula and parameters values to determine theoretical maximum data rate?

- Luo, Quyuan, et al. "Resource scheduling in edge computing: A survey." IEEE Communications Surveys & Tutorials 23.4 (2021): 2131-2165.

Comment: shannon capacity gives just an upper bound for the theoretically possible data rate over a given link. Practical applications like yours *must* have a lower data rate, because you cannot transmit infinitely long words. So, no, this is not the right formula – this is just an upper bound.

Comment: The formula just simply doesn't describe the data rate. It describes a theoretical maximum data rate that some hypothetical transmission system could achieve.

Comment: Third time: your formula doesn't describe what you think it describes! It's not that the formula is wrong, it just doesn't give you what you think you get.

Comment: That's no problem, you're very welcome to ask! Do you understand the difference between a *theoretical upper bound for an achievable data rate* and the *data rate of an actual system*?

Comment: @MarcusMüller. I would say yes now. While the theoretical upper bound gives an idea of the best-case scenario and provides a target to aim for, the actual system data rate gives a realistic measure of performance. The actual system data rate always less than or equal to the theoretical upper bound because the affect of some other factor. So now what should I do, adding some noise that represent some error or overheads?

Comment: The question now is what you *want* to actually calculate! The transmission rate is a property of the actual system you're building, and I don't know that.

Comment: Totally confused now on what you have, what you're free to model, and what you want to derive from that model.

Comment: as said, I'm not clear about what parts of your system are set, and which you're free to model as you see fit. It seems, for example, that you don't have actual transmission systems for your links, but are trying to model them as theoretically perfect transmission systems with infinite block length. But then you insist on using the word "data rate" for something that the both of us have already established is not the data rate, but an upper limit for all possible rates. So, I'm honestly just confused about what your model of your system looks like.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  I appreciate your feedback. I modified the content to focus on what we are actually calculating. I changed the terms to "theoretical upper bound," which is Shannon's capacity, instead of "transmission rate." Now, I need to find the transmission delay. Is my Shannon formula correct? Or are you still concerned about the lower bounds? If so, what action should be taken?

Comment: so, it, again, depends on what you're modelling. Your model is for a flat AWGN channel (or one modeled as being time- and frequency-invariant through finding an expectation "hidden" in that factor $h$), it seems, with adjustable path loss exponent; but that exponent needs to appear in the exponent of $D$, not as a factor. As recognized, this formula just gives you the highest possible speed, and any actual system with finite delay is necessarily below that, and will in a realistic scenario, be quite a bit below that. However, that *is* a proper model assumption, but then you must be honest to…

Comment: … yourself and your reader: the delay you get is a better-than-best-case bound for the delay of a system, not the actual delay of a system that can exist. That's actually an OK result! You can say something like "because the parameters of our channel quality estimation were chosen sufficiently conservatively, it is to be expected that actual implementations might actually achieve the lower bound for the transmission delay that we find". But it *is* important to know that you're *not* modeling a real system, you're modeling a *system which cannot exist but helps to derive performance bounds*.

Comment: Well if you're simulating a real system, then you have transceivers in that – with actual data rates which aren't arbitrary! So, figure out the data rate your transceivers use for any given SNR.

Comment: Yes, I've utilized realistic parameters such as power and bandwidth. The ones mentioned above are the Shannon formula/parameter values for which I'm seeking feedback.

Comment: I think you got that? You just said you're modeling a real system, but in the next comment, you say you only used realistic values for power and such, so there's no real system that you're modelling. I'm giving up here, sorry.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. I am simulating real system using realistic values not arbitrary. Thanks dear for valuable time.